# Distributed and deployed the WSO2 API Manager components

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed a distributed [WSO2 API Manager Componentes](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager). This works very well but when I subscribe to an API and generate a token this error is shown:

> "Token revoke failed : HTTP error code : 500"

The log :

```
[2015-08-12 13:28:59,623] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: Host name verification failed for host : 189.9.134.48
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Host name verification failed for host : 189.9.134.48
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.ClientSSLSetupHandler.verify(ClientSSLSetupHandler.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:285)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.outboundTransport(SSLIOSession.java:420)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.outputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:150)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.writable(BaseIOReactor.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:346)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:320)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:604)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-08-12 13:28:59,627]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2015-08-12 13:28:59,628]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Wed Aug 12 13:29:29 BRT 2015
[2015-08-12 13:28:59,629]  INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing token 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101500, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in Sender
[2015-08-12 13:28:59,635] ERROR - subscription-add:jag java.lang.RuntimeException: Token revoke failed : HTTP error code : 500
[2015-08-12 13:29:09,641] ERROR - SourceHandler I/O error: Conexão fechada pela outra ponta
```

How can I solve this problem? I'm using APIM 1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to solve this issue. The following is **recommended in production environment**. The second way **isn't recommanded in production** environment

**Way 1**

1. You are having issue with verifying hostname "189.9.134.48". 189.9.134.48 should be your Common Name (CN) when generating your keys. You have to import your public key certificate of WSO2 IS server into WSO2 APIM server. You may use the following command inorder to extract the public key certificate from your keystore. Go inside `<IS_HOME>/repository/resources/security/` directory

   ```
   keytool -export -keystore <IS_Store> -alias <alias_of_IS_certificate> -file <IS_certificate>.cer
   ```
2. This SSL Ceritificate of the IS should be imported into the client-truststore.jks of APIM server.
   Shutdown the APIM server if it's up.
   Go to `<APIM_HOME>/repository/resources/security/` directory.
   Import the public key of appserver to the client-truststore.jks file using the following command
   in terminal.

   ```
   keytool -import -alias <alias_of_IS_certificate> -file <IS_certificate>.cer -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon
   ```

   Restart the APIM server.

**Way 2**

Set the `<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">` element to `AllowAll` in `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml` file's HTTPS transport sender configuration. For example, `<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>`.

This parameter verifies the hostname of the certificate of a server when the API Manager acts as a client and does outbound service calls.

Comment: Thanks. I put this configuration at the gateway node, keymanager node and store node. But this mensage is showing: " Token revoke failed : HTTP error code : 500 " <br> I tried the second way.

Comment: What's your Identity Server Version? Can you please attached the latest logs here? Have you noticed above exception or, is it resolved?

Comment: I am using WSO2 API Manager 1.9.  The file is at [www.trajanux.com.br/wso2-apigw-errors.log]